# Filter variable from server on client side

Tags: node.js, client-side

I have a Node Js server that sends a list of laws to the client side throught a variable . How can I filter the variable in the client side (according to a search of the client in an input box)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have json file
you can use JSON.parse() and then filter array!

When receiving data from a web server, the data is always a string.

Parse the data with JSON.parse(), and the data becomes a JavaScript object.

If you use XMLHttpRequest:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

You send a request to server and receive a string response.
You should covert string(Json) to array.
this.response is your json that server send to client!

Comment: Sorry, I´m new at Node Js, How do you use JSON.parse()

Comment: Updated answer!